# How To Use Response.Redirect(FileDownloadUrl) in the CustomButtonCallback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, response

I have a custom button in a GridView in ASP.Net with c#.

How I can use:

```
Response.Redirect(FileDownloadUrl)
```

in CustomButtonCallback procedure ?

---

when i Using this command
    Response.Redirect(FileDownloadUrl, false)

I am getting the following error
"Response.Redirect cannot be called in a page Callback."

Comment: Please show the code. You may use JavaScript - window.location.href.

Answer (score 0):

> Response.Redirect(FileDownloadUrl, false)

Comment: Response.Redirect(FileDownloadUrl, false)

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's not the answer to your question. But maybe you should use `Server.Transfer` instead of `Response.Redirect`. You can save additional trip to the server .